# Excel search for cell value and delete row using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to search a sheet using openpyxl and then remove the entire row when a value is found. When I attempt the below code I am receiving TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'
Can someone advise  how I can iterate on a cell but then reference the row from the parent loop?

Here is my code:

```
wb = xl.load_workbook(filename)
sheet = wb[os.path.splitext(filename)[0]]

for row in sheet.rows:
    for cell in row:
        if cell.value == "Report Generated By  :":
            sheet.delete_rows(row, 1)
```

Comment: You want to pass in the row number rather than the whole row.

Comment: I thought I was passing on the row number with the (row) value followed by the number of rows to delete? If this is not the case can you help clarify how to do so?

Comment: Try `sheet.delete_rows(cell.row)` though you should also be aware that deleting rows while looping over them can have unexpected consequences…

Comment: This produces the error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'tuple'

Answer (score 1):

After reading up on this article: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.cell.cell.html

I discovered I could solve this with the following statement:

sheet.delete_rows(cell.row, 1)

Comment: Which is exactly what I suggested.

Comment: I misread your comment as cell, row which caused the error in my latest comment. I'll see if I can mark your comment as the solution.